# is it possible to set Maxdate to Calendar control in Ext.Net?

Tags: calendar, ext.net

I am working with Ext.Net 1.2

**I am using Calendar control.** I want to disable all previous date only calendar can enabled from today's date.

like Date Picker had functionality like **MaxDate="<%# DateTime.Now %>"**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to call `.DataBind()` on the Control, or just set `AutoDataBind="true"`.

**Example**

```
<ext:DatePicker runat="server" MaxDate="<%# DateTime.Now %>" AutoDataBind="true" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't want to set MaxDate in Date Picker I want same functionality in calender control.